# php comma separated value no inserting in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to simple insert comma separated value in table field.But I don't get any cause why it's not working.

```
<?php

$array = array('1', '2', '3');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO like(user_id,like_data)
VALUES ('1','$comma_separated')";

if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
}

?>
```

Here like_data field I have taken varchar.

It is giving sql syntax error.

Comment: I think `like` is a reserved word! So put it in \`, like: INSERT INTO \`like`

Comment: It's come from database connection. Like as 

$connection=mysqli("host","user","pass","db");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put ` around `LIKE` since it's a reserved word in SQL! So it should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `like`
```

Comment: Voted you up because you were first to spot the issue and put it in a comment even though your answer came late and that the question is now closed :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thanks :D I always forget to mark a question as a Duplicate! And if i answered it i'm like asking my self: Wait, wasn't this question asked before. (Have to remember my self more to thing about this)

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` is a MySQL reserved keyword.

[MySQL reserved Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html)

Solutions:

1) avoid using `like` as table name.

2) Add Database name before `like`: `dbName.like`

3) Add a backtick (`) against the like :

```
INSERT INTO `like`(user_id,like_data) VALUES ('1','$comma_separated')
```

Comment: haha !! oh !! Thank you. this is just an unconsciousness.

Answer (score 1):

You must not use the keywords for the table name

if you use them you just have to have them in backticks  like this

```
INSERT INTO `like` (user_id,like_data) VALUES ('1','$comma_separated')
```